# a2ensite does it need to be used for ServerAlias

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

On Debian does a2ensite command need to be used after adding or deleting ServerAlias entries inside an Include file [I have alot of domains in there] inside a virtual host entry or can I just do apachectl graceful?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sales.com
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/sales.com-domainlist.txt
DocumentRoot /var/www/sales.com
<Directory /var/www/sales.com>
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I only have experience with restarting apache [on centos and windows] anytime it needs to reload the updated configuration files.

Comment: I don't think the `Include` directive works as a parameter for another directive.

Comment: I just transfered a pile of domains over, your right it doesn't. It also didn't like a new line between each domain in the txt file. :( And I had to put ServerAlias in the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a2ensite` command creates a symbolic link to the particular configuration file from sites-enabled to sites-available. If you have already enabled a site's config and make modifications to it you do not need to enable it again and can simply use `graceful` or `reload`.

Ie:

- The apache2.conf file has an include for sites-enabled/*
- You make a site specific config file in sites-available/
- When you run `a2ensite` it creates a symbolic link to the file from sites-enabled to sites-available thus making Apache pick it up from the sites-enabled/* include. *All `a2dissite` does is delete the symlink.*

So `a2ensite` is effectively just `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitename.conf`. So, once it has been done changes to the already linked file do not affect the link you just need Apache to reload config.

Comment: Thanks, so I only need to use that command when adding a new virtual host.